# How to set the First link of pagination in CI be shown?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

How to fix the present of pagination ?
I want to my pagination alway be shown fully (First Prev 1 2 3 4 Next Last)
Now, it is not shown the First link, just when go to the Last.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to my pagination always be shown fully

Initializing the pagination class with `$config['num_links'];` to any high number like 999 should work, but you *might* not see the First/Last links (haven't tested).

The CI pagination class is a bit rough around the edges and really lacking in features, so if you intend to use it *as-is*, I wouldn't wrestle too much with it. Take what you can get.

Comment: I can't think of any off the top of my head. I wrote my own, but it isn't something that should be released to the public in it's current state :D. If you have specific needs, you may be able to extend the pagination class and make a few changes. So, did this solution work or not? You didn't say, I can only assume that it did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = [
                'base_url'   =>   base_url('admin/dashboard/'),
                'per_page'   =>   5,
                'total_rows' =>   $this->articlesmodel->num_rows(),
                'full_tag_open' => "<ul class='pagination'>",
                'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
                'first_tag_open' =>'<li>',
                'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'first_link'    =>  'First',
                'last_tag_open' =>'<li>',
                'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'last_link'     =>  'Last',
                'next_tag_open' =>'<li>',
                'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'prev_tag_open' =>'<li>',
                'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'num_tag_open' =>'<li>',
                'num_tag_close' => '</li>',
                'cur_tag_open' => "<li class='active'><a>",
                'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>'

    ];
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the answer? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context why this is an answer to the question. It might be obvious to an experienced user but not to everyone.